# using new c++11 feature in older versions

Tags: c++, c++11, compilation, compiler-warnings

```
  int main(){

    int x{1};
    cout << "Value of x = " << x << endl;
}
```

Here i use the "{}" syntax to initialize my variable x and its perfectly fine and working

```
Value of x = 1
```

while compiling it with `g++ --std=c++11`

After deleting the resultant `.out` file and recompile it with `g++ --std=c++98` i get the following warning.

```
main.cpp:10:7: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
  int x{1};
```

But while running the .out file i still get the desired output.

Here i want to know whats actually happening. why am getting the correct output. weather the compiler is recompiling it with `--std=c++11` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC is obliging you and compiling the code as C++98 with some extensions. It may accept some or all C++11 features, or it may not. The default behavior is usually to accept whatever code it may understand, even if it's not strictly valid C++.

For strict compliance you may add the `-pedantic-errors` switch. It will make GCC consider only true ISO C++ (as specified by the `--std` flag) as valid, as well as add diagnostics to some other potentially harmful constructs.

Comment: You could also turn on "warnings as errors" -Werror